# Liquid Animation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I have seen one animation today

[enter link description here](http://www.catsuka.com/interf/vignettes_news/gif/mtvident_masanobuhiraoka.gif)

I think that in Blender can be achieved with Freestyle, Toon shader and Shadeless but liquid animation?

Kind regards
Ros

Comment: I don't understand what your question is - what exactly do you want to know or are having trouble with?

Comment: freestyle, toon and postprocesing will "cartoonize" whatever you model in blender, fluid simulations included.

Comment: I think the problem is more about morphing